# Suppose two dice are thrown and the sum of both numbers is observed is odd. Determine the probability that the sum is less than 8.

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

I tried to solve the problem by making all the sums as sample space and then counting for the sums that were odd and less than 8. I know the formula for the conditional probability but I am not sure of how to apply it there.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What do you know about conditional probability?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by making all the sums as sample space and then counting for the sums that were odd and less than 8. I know the formula for the conditional probability but I am not sure of how to apply it there.

Comment: Your sample space is just the sums that are odd.  The probability of each is rescaled to make the total $1$.  Then we ask the chance the sum is less than $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the formula for conditional probability $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

In this case, assign $A$ as "sum less than $8$" and $B$ as "sum is odd".  As such, we have $P(A\cap B)=\frac13$ and $P(B)=\frac12$.  Therefore, the answer is $\frac23$.